# Can I put two divs next to each other and when one is remove the other expands to fill the space?

Tags: html, css

Say I have 2 divs next to each other in a container of fixed width. Horizontally next to each other that is. Then say one div is removed, how can i get the other div to fill up the space next to it where the other div was? As in it should expand its width.

Comment: How do you remove the div? If you are using javascript, you can programatically set the other div's width when the user initiate the remove event.

Comment: it just wont show depending on cases but the problem is the 2 divs do not know the state of the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/cFeFx/) a way to do it without Javascript.

Comment: Hey CircleB thats almost what I need except the left div wont expand right if the right div is not visible. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this will work in IE... I've tested it in Chrome, Firefox and Safari, but this might work for you.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/W9USV/) is a fiddle for it.

CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 400px;
}
#left {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #ddd;
    float: left;
}
#right {
    width:100%;
    float: right;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    background: #CCC;
}
#left + #right {
    width: 200px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
function removeElement(divNum) {
  var d = document.getElementById('container');
  var olddiv = document.getElementById(divNum);
  d.removeChild(olddiv);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="left"></div>
   <div id="right"></div>
   <input onclick="removeElement('left')" type="button" value="X"/>
</div>
```

Comment: hmm I was hoping there would be some css trickery to get this done without js. I could use tables i know but would prefer divs

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to manipulate the CSS properties and visibility. In [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/XS7V3/5/) I alter the widths.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `display: table;` but it won't work in IE 7 and below. Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Test div</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #container {
            width: 400px;
            display: table;
        }

        #row-container {
            display: table-row;
        }

        #left, #right {
            display: table-cell;
            height: 200px;
        }

        #left {
            background-color: red;
        }

        #right {
            background-color: blue;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="row-container">
        <div id="left"></div>
        <div id="right"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```